# Implementing an interpreter for "if" statement in scheme

Tags: scheme, interpreter

I am trying to implement an interpreter in scheme. For now i implemented some part of it, but i am having problems with "if" statement. Here is the grammar:

```
<s6> -> <expr>
        | <define>

<define> -> ( define IDENT <expr> )

<expr> -> NUMBER
          | IDENT
          | <if>

<if> -> ( if <expr> <expr> <expr> )
```

Here is the code i have written so far:

```
(define get-operator (lambda (op-symbol)
(cond
    ((equal? op-symbol '+) +)
    ((equal? op-symbol '-) -)
    ((equal? op-symbol '*) *)
    ((equal? op-symbol '/) /)
    (else (error "s6-interpret: operator not implemented -->" op-symbol)))))


(define if-stmt? (lambda (e)
(and (list? e) (equal? (car e) 'if) (= (length e) 4))))

(define define-stmt? (lambda (e)
(and (list? e) (equal? (car e) 'define) (symbol? (cadr e)) (= (length e) 3))))


(define get-value (lambda (var env)
(cond
    ((null? env) (error "s6-interpret: unbound variable -->" var))
    ((equal? (caar env) var) (cdar env))
    (else (get-value var (cdr env))))))


(define extend-env (lambda (var val old-env)
(cons (cons var val) old-env)))


(define repl (lambda (env)
(let* (
    (dummy1 (display "cs305> "))
    (expr (read))
    (new-env (if (define-stmt? expr)
                (extend-env (cadr expr) (s6-interpret (caddr expr) env) env)env))
    (val (if (define-stmt? expr)
                (cadr expr)
                (s6-interpret expr env)))
    (dummy2 (display "cs305: "))
    (dummy3 (display val))
    (dummy4 (newline))
    (dummy4 (newline)))
(repl new-env))))


(define s6-interpret (lambda (e env)
(cond
    ((number? e) e)
    ((symbol? e) (get-value e env))
    ((not (list? e)) (error "s6-interpret: cannot evaluate -->" e))
    (if-stmt? e) (if (eq? (cadr e) 0) (map s6-interpret (cadddr e)) (map s6-interpret(caddr e))))
    (else
        (let ((operands (map s6-interpret (cdr e) (make-list (length (cdr e)) env)))
                (operator (get-operator (car e))))
            (apply operator operands))))))


(define cs305-interpreter (lambda () (repl '())))
```

The define statement works well. My code also includes implementation of some basic math operators, you can ignore them. My problem is, the "if" statement i implemented does not work as i expect. When i write "(if 1 (+ 2 5) 9)" it prints out (+ 2 5) but actually i want it to print out 7, which is 2+5. I think there is a problem about my recursion. Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have written for if statements never triggers, because if statements are lists of length 4, not 3:

```
(define if-stmt? (lambda (e)
  (and (list? e)
       (equal? (car e) 'if)
       (= (length e) 3))))


> (length '(if condition then-clause else-clause))
4
> (if-stmt? '(if condition then-clause else-clause))
#f
```

It would probably make more sense to accept any list that starts with the symbol "if" as an if statement. If it doesn't have a legal length, that just means it's a *broken* if statement, not that it's something else entirely (unless the language you're writing an interpreter for is unusual for a Lisp in this respect).

There is indeed also something wrong with your recursion, in that you're not using it in this case. When if-stmt? triggers, you are not calling s6-interpret again. The following would be closer to correct:

```
((if-stmt? e)
 (s6-interpret
  (if (eq? (cadr e) 0)
     (cadddr e)
     (caddr e))
  env))
```

Note that there are also other irregularities with your implementation, including the if statement. For instance, it is not conventional that "0" evaluates as false, and certainly very unconventional that #f evaluates as true.

Check what the Scheme implementation actually does to see what is considered conventional/correct. You can also refer to [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/), which is comparatively short and readable for a language specification.

A few hints about code legibility:

You should use conventional indentation. This will make your code easier to read. If you're using a Scheme-aware editor, the editor can likely help you with this. For instance, in DrRacket, just press "tab" when at the start of a line and this line will be fixed for you. You'll need to insert newlines as appropriate.

Scheme has a syntax especially for defining functions. Use it. You have likely been taught that you *could* implement everything by binding lambdas to symbol names -- functions are not special. That's an important theoretical point, but it's not a good idea to do this in practice. The following are essentially equivalent, but the latter is shorter and easier to read.

```
(define f (lambda (a b) (+ a b)))
(define (f a b) (+ a b))
```

Comment: Oh, you are right thanks but now i am editing the question that was not really what i wanted to ask. But thanks for warning about this

Comment: Well i solved it but i will consider your advises as well. Thanks